# Passing a generic function as parameter

Tags: java, functional-programming

Ran into this idea and I'm curious if it's possible.

I'm trying to make a single function that can test ALL of my sorting algorithms dynamically. I want to be able to pass the sorting function as a parameter and the algorithm will use the sorting function with it's own dynamic parameters. This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class manyFunctions{
    int[] mergeSort(int[] myArray){
        ...work here;
        return sortedArray;
    }

    int[] otherSort(int[] myArray){
        ...work here;
        return sortedArray;
        }
}

class mainClass{
   public static void main(String[]Args){
      test(manyFunctions.mergeSort);
      test(manyFunctions.otherSort);

   }

     boolean test(function someSortFunction){
        int n; // number of trials
        for (int i=0; i<=n ; i++) {
        int[] A = generateArray() // another function I made
            if (isSorted(someSortFunction(A)) = false) {
                return false;
            }
        }
     return true;
 }
```

I can't figure out how to do this with the little bit I know about lambda expressions and function pointers. If it's possible, this technique would come in handy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Note: This answer is based on Java 8 and newer. This does not apply to Java 7, as Java 7 does not support Lambda

For starters, your test function is wrong in multiple places:

```
boolean test(function someSortFunction){//This is not how you pass functions
    int n; //this has to be initialized
    for (int i=0; i<=n ; i++) {//Depending on how n is used, you may have to use < instead of <=
        int[] A = generateArray()//Missing semi-colon
        if (isSorted(someSortFunction(A)) = false) {//Comparing is done with ==, not =
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

In order to pass a function, you can either use `Consumer<Void>`, `Supplier<Void>`, `Predicate<Void>` or `Function<Void, Void>` (don't use `Void` as the type if you have return values)

Supplier defines return type, Consumer defines input type, and function both. Meaning:

- Use Predicate when you have a boolean return type with arguments
- Use Supplier when you have a return type
- Use Consumer when you have an argument
- Use Function when you have both an argument and a return value

Since you have both arguments and return types, use `Function`. The first argument you give it is the argument it receives, and the second is the return type. For an instance, in your case, this would be:

```
boolean test(Function<int[], int[]> someFunction)
```

Using `Function` requires calling `apply` to execute the method:

```
int[] res = someFunction.apply(input);
```

Before I move on, I'd like to take a second to mention naming conventions. In Java, class names always start with an upper case letter. Instances and functions start with a lower case letter. So your classes would be:

```
public class ManyFunctions {...}
public class MainClass {...}
```

Passing methods are not done using `someClass.someFunction`. In your case, since you are not using static methods, you need to create an instance:

```
ManyFunctions functions = new ManyFunctions();
```

now, you pass the functions:

```
test(functions::mergeSort);
```

if you make the methods static, you can just skip the instance and use the class name directly:

```
test(ManyFunctions::mergeSort);
```

So your class would be:

```
class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ManyFunctions manyFunctions = new ManyFunctions();
        test(manyFunctions::mergeSort);//Notice the missing "()" and arguments
        test(manyFunctions::otherSort);

    }

    boolean test(Function<int[], int[]> someSortFunction){
        int n = 10;//THIS HAS TO BE INITIALIZED! Otherwise, it won't compile
        for (int i=0; i<=n ; i++) {
            int[] A = generateArray();
            if (isSorted(someSortFunction.apply(A)) == false) {//comparing is done with ==
                return false;
            }
         }
         return true;
    }
}//Don't know if it was a copy-paste problem or not, but you had a missing bracket
```

Comment: when the return type is boolean then the functional interface should be `Predicate`

Comment: I was looking at `test()` method itself

Comment: There are no methods being passed as arguments with a boolean return type in OP's code though (had to post a new comment, was too late to edit the previous one)

Comment: @SharonBenAsher `test()` is never passed anywhere. The only methods being passed have `int[]` return types

Comment: I apologize that, by trying to simplify my question/code, I made some distracting mistakes. The meat of the question is there though and your answer is really helpful and interesting! Thank you!